# [Oracle Responsys]Supplemental: Supplemental_table has no extraction key that matches fully to the list

Tags: oracle, responsys, rpl

My email is showing errors and the problems seems to be with my supplemental table.

This are the errors I get:

Supplemental data source: CA_3rd_email_2023 associated with: 2023_ma_vlmr_ca_3rd_email_DRAFT_test is invalid for the reason below: Supplemental: CA_3rd_email_2023 has no extraction key that matches fully to the list.

Supplemental: CA_3rd_email_2023 has no extraction key that matches fully to the list.

I tried checking the checkbox on all properties as lookup keys but that didn't seem to work.